# Play (Scala) Configuration Map Object

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration, typesafe-config

I would like to access the following configuration

```
customers {
  "cust1" {
    clientId: "id1"
    attrs {
      att1: "str1"
      att2: "str2"
      att3: "str3"
      att4: "str4"
    }
  }
  "cust2" {
    clientId: "id2"
    attrs: {
      att1: "faldfjalfj"
      att2: "reqwrewrqrq"
    }
  }
  "cust3" {
    clientId: "id3"
    attrs {
      att2: "xvcbzxbv"
    }
  }
}
```

as a `Map[String, CustomerConfig]` where `CustomerConfig` is

```
package models

import play.api.ConfigLoader
import com.typesafe.config.Config // I added this import in order to make the documentation snippet compile to the best of my knowledge.

case class CustomerConfig(clientId: String, attrs: Map[String, String])

object CustomerConfig {
  implicit val configLoader: ConfigLoader[CustomerConfig] = new ConfigLoader[CustomerConfig] {
  def load(rootConfig: Config, path: String): CustomerConfig = {
    val config = rootConfig.getConfig(path)
    CustomerConfig(
      clientId = config.getString("clientId"),
      attrs = config.get[Map[String, String]]("attrs").map { case (attr, attrVal) =>
        (attr, attrVal)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

For reference, this is how I am currently attempting to reference it:

```
  val resellerEnvMap = conf.get[Map[String, CustomerConfig]]("customers").map {
    case (customer, customerConfig) =>
      customer -> customerConfig.attrs.map {
        case (attr, attrVal) =>
          attr -> new Obj(attrVal, customerConfig.clientId)
      }
  }
```

based on [custom config loader documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaConfig#ConfigLoader).

The problem is that `config.get[A]` does not exist (neither does `config.getMap[K, V]`) per the what I believe to be the [API docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/com/typesafe/config/Config.html). I would like a way to populate that `map` from the configuration file. My end goal is to populate anything in the functional vicinity of `Map[String, Map[String, (String, String)]]` where the first `String` is the customer name, the 2nd is attribute name, the 3rd is the attribute value, and lastly, the 4th is the client ID.

Answer (score 5):

Play 2.6 uses com.typesafe:config 1.3.2 while the link you posted seems to be from version 2? Here's one way to do it:

```
object CustomerConfig {
  implicit val configLoader: ConfigLoader[CustomerConfig] = new ConfigLoader[CustomerConfig] {
    def load(rootConfig: Config, path: String): CustomerConfig = {
      val config = rootConfig.getConfig(path)
      import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

      val attrConfig = config.getConfig("attrs")
      CustomerConfig(
        clientId = config.getString("clientId"),
        attrs = attrConfig.entrySet().asScala.map { entry =>
          (entry.getKey, attrConfig.getString(entry.getKey))
        }.toMap
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, @Jaime! Could you possibly take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449346/ordered-objects-in-play-scala-typesafe-config and let me if this is possible?

Comment: @juanchito your other question is answered :)