# *Ordered* objects in Play (Scala) typesafe config

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-config

How do I access the *ordered* list of `customers` in the following .conf in Play 2.6.x (Scala):

```
customers {
  "cust1" {
    env1 {
      att1: "str1"
      att2: "str2"
    }
    env2 {
      att1: "str3"
      att2: "str5"
    }
    env3 {
      att1: "str2"
      att2: "str6"
    }
    env4 {
      att1: "str1"
      att2: "str2"
    }
  }
  "cust2" {
    env1 {
      att1: "faldfjalfj"
      att2: "reqwrewrqrq"
    }
    env2 {
      att1: "falalfj"
      att2: "reqwrrq"
    }
  }
  "cust3" {
    env3 {
      att1: "xvcbzxbv"
      att2: "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

`List("cust1", "cust2", "cust3")`, in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example should work:

```
val config : Configuration = ???
config.getObject("customers").entrySet().asScala.map(_.getKey).toList
```

**Edit**

If customers are in lexicographical order than you can order call `.sorted`

If changing your config doesn't affect your already implemented logic than you can restructure your config like this:

```
customers : [
  {
    name : "cust1"
    env1 {
      att1: "str1"
      att2: "str2"
    }
    env2 {
      att1: "str3"
      att2: "str5"
    }
    env3 {
      att1: "str2"
      att2: "str6"
    }
    env4 {
      att1: "str1"
      att2: "str2"
    }
  }
   {
    name : "cust2"
    env1 {
      att1: "faldfjalfj"
      att2: "reqwrewrqrq"
    }
    env2 {
      att1: "falalfj"
      att2: "reqwrrq"
    }
  }
  {
    name: "cust3"
    env3 {
      att1: "xvcbzxbv"
      att2: "hello"
    }
  }
  {
    name : "bob"
    env1 {
      att1: "str1"
      att2: "str2"
    }
    env2 {
      att1: "str3"
      att2: "str5"
    }
    env3 {
      att1: "str2"
      att2: "str6"
    }
    env4 {
      att1: "str1"
      att2: "str2"
    }
  }
  {
    name : "john"
    env1 {
      att1: "faldfjalfj"
      att2: "reqwrewrqrq"
    }
    env2 {
      att1: "falalfj"
      att2: "reqwrrq"
    }
  }
  {
    name: "jack"
    env3 {
      att1: "xvcbzxbv"
      att2: "hello"
    }
  }
]
```

and with [pureconfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) you can do the following:

```
import pureconfig.loadConfigOrThrow

final case class Named(name: String)

loadConfigOrThrow[List[Named]]("customers").map(_.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeClass @Inject()(config: Configuration) {
  Logger.debug("Customers from config: " + config.underlying.getConfig("customers"))
}
```

Will give you.

```
Customers from config: Config(SimpleConfigObject(
    {"cust1":{
        "env1":{"att1":"str1","att2":"str2"},
        "env2":{"att1":"str3","att2":"str5"},
        "env3":{"att1":"str2","att2":"str6"},
        "env4":{"att1":"str1","att2":"str2"}},
    "cust2":{
        "env1":{"att1":"faldfjalfj","att2":"reqwrewrqrq"},
        "env2":{"att1":"falalfj","att2":"reqwrrq"}},
   "cust3":{
        "env3":{"att1":"xvcbzxbv","att2":"hello"}}}))
```

You obviously have to then transform this if you want to work with objects.